# Onedrive on linux without root?

Tags: linux, curl, wget

I have 80GB of data on OneDrive. I want to move it to a different cloud provider. My Internet connection at home is not too fast, and as I have a seedbox (VPS) on a fast data connection I would like to use that to perform the transfer.

I don't have root access, and using VNC to connect to the seedbox and download files through Firefox is unreliable and slow, and fails after only partial downloads.

I cannot install most command line tools for OneDrive due to lack of root access. Is there any workarounds?

Comment: You mean you don't have elevated privileges and can't use sudo? You don't actually need root for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by using [OneDeath](https://gitlab.com/VADemon/onedeath)

Since my seed box did not have lua. I installed lua by compiling it from source following this [guide](https://www.programmersought.com/article/4190182067/).

Basically, the path I used was the absolute path to the bin folder on my desktop `/home11/username/bin/`.

i.e for both readline and ncurses

```bsh
./configure --prefix=/home11/username/bin/
make
make install
```

and the following changes to the makefiles
`lua/src/Makefile`

```bsh
CC= gcc -std=gnu99 -fPIC
MYCFLAGS=-I/usr/local/readline/include
MYLDFLAGS=-L$/home11/username/bin/include/readline/lib -L/home11/username/bin/include/ncurses -L$/home11/username/bin/include/ncurses/lib
 
linux:
$(MAKE) $(ALL) SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline -lncurses"
```

and `lua/Makefile`

```bsh
INSTALL_TOP=/home11/username/bin/lua
```

then executing the main.lua from OneDeath with the following command

```bsh
/home11/username/bin/lua/bin/lua main.lua <share url>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Rclone](https://rclone.org) should be able to interact with oneDrive.

If you follow the [installation instructions for "Installation from precompiled binary"](https://rclone.org/install/#linux-installation-from-precompiled-binary) you should be able to do this without root access.

Comment: Is it possible to also access the web gui?